# SharePoint:DateTimeControl, Error Rendering Control: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am exploring on trying to create a custom webpart and I am encountering this error:

In my source, I have a table in which a cell will contain SharePoint:DateTimeControl.

```
<asp:Table ID="interviewerAndApplicants" Visible="False" runat="server" Width="50%">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>    
            Interview Timeslot:  <SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="interviewSlot" runat="server" />
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

The weird thing is, if the `SharePoint:DateTimeControl` is NOT within a table cell, it displays perfectly in the design. However when it is placed within a cell, it will cause the error:

> *"Error Rendering Control: Object reference not set to an instance of
>   an object"*

in the designer view.

What exactly am I doing wrong/ missed out on doing? Thanks.